# Github Pages: AJAX to subfolder error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, github, github-pages

I'm hosting an in-development web app on Github pages

The app includes the following script to fetch all audio file names from subfolder /audio

```
$.ajax({
   url: "audio/",
   success: function (data) {
      $(data).find("a:contains('.mp3')").each(function () {
         console.log(this.href)
      });
   }
});
```

This works fine on localhost, but when I host this project with Github Pages, this AJAX request returns an error:  GET http://taylorbf.github.io/ToneJam/audio/ 404 (Not Found)

(The project is at http://taylorbf.github.io/ToneJam/.)

If I manually navigate to:

http://taylorbf.github.io/ToneJam/audio   No Github Pages here

http://taylorbf.github.io/ToneJam/audio/fmblips.mp3    Does show an audio file

I thought maybe I needed to add an index.html html to the /audio subfolder to initialize it as a Github Pages site, but that does not fix my AJAX issue.

I'd love to know more about what is going on here and why my AJAX is not valid in this situation.

Comment: I'd try absolute url instead of "audio/". Github pages have probably different routing then normal hosted website.

Comment: Good idea, but this still gives a 404 - Not Found error.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Or at least 99% the same.